# jQuery animation infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am pretty new to Javascript and jQuery and I have this jQuery animation, that I want to loop infinite, but I can't seem to get it functioning since I don't really know how to reset the properties that it animates, before restarting it. Some help making this animation into an infinite loop and an explanation of it would be much appreciated!

This is what I have so far:

```
function animation(){
   $('#logo img').fadeIn(2000);
   $('#logo img').delay(500).animate({'margin-top':'2%'}, 1000);
   $('#infoOne').delay(3500).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
   $('#infoTwo').delay(8500).fadeIn(2000).delay(2500).fadeOut(1000);
   $('#link').delay(14000).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
   $('#bottom').delay(14000).animate({opacity: 1, 'bottom':'0'}, 1900);
   $('#logos').delay(14000).animate({opacity: 1, 'margin-top':'10%'}, 2000);
};

   setInterval(animation(), 16000);
```

Comment: can you please post HTML and CSS too?

Comment: Just clear out the CSS properties at the start of the function?

Comment: I am new to Javascript and jQuery, so I would still need some guidance on how to clear out my CSS properties in the start of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a lot of delay that is used  to delay animations in a queue (i.e event execution queue). You can use `stop`, `finish` or [clearQueue](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) before starting your animation again in `setInterval`.

Comment: Since I am new to Javascript and jQuery I would still need some guidance as to where I would need to add this in my animation, in order to reset my added CSS properties before restarting my animation.

Answer (score 1):

Hеy, you can do the same animations with CSS3 Animations. Try to not animate with jQuery, because it is adding inline styling to the element, which can bring to some issues with the application performance. Just write the following CSS:

```css
#logo img {
  animation: 2s fadeIn 1 alternate backwards, 1s transform 0.5s infinite alternate backwards;
}
#infoOne {
  animation: 2s fadeIn 3.5s infinite alternate backwards;
}
#infoTwo {
  animation: 2s fadeIn 8.5s infinite alternate backwards;
}
#link {
  animation: 2s fadeIn 14s 1 alternate backwards;
}
#bottom {
  animation: 2s toBottom 5s 1 backwards ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
#logos {
  animation: 1s fadeIn 1 alternate backwards, 5s toBottom 0.5s infinite alternate backwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes toBottom {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes transform {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="https://blog.polymer-project.org/images/logos/p-logo.png" width="50px" />
</div>

<p id="infoOne">Welcome to the Polymer website!</p>
<p id="infoTwo">Here we have some answer to christian24 and solving it with CSS.</p>

<a href="http://polymer-project.org">Polymer Project website</a>

<p id="bottom">BOTTOM TEXT</p>

<p id="logos">LOGOS HERE</p>
```